# best way to pass input through ajax

Tags: php, jquery

as i want to send some sensitive information like 'user id' through ajax which is the best way to transfer them. right now i am just concatenating with the html tag's ids and then splitting and using them . please suggest a better way . i hope there must be one for this

Comment: you have any code that u use now that u want manipulated?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to transfer identification values (such as user_id) is to not transfer them at all. If you can, I'd grab the current user_id from **a session**, that way it isn't possible for a user to change that "user_id" to immatate someone else.

However if this option doesn't fit your application, you can always hash the user_id on the server side, such as:

```
md5($user_id . "randomsalthere");
```

Then when you check the request, see if:

`$_POST['secret_hash'] == md5($_POST['user_id'], 'randomsalthere');`

Links:

[Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)

[Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: i ll go with u Mike. i ll md5 my usr-id and then append it to html ids. i hope md5(usr-id) cant be decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Would POST work for you? Only the User would be able to sniff out the POST parameter,

Comment: pete can u give a small sample of it or just a tip for it

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way would be to use [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), regardless whether you are using `POST` or `GET`.

Another question that comes to mind: Do you really need to send this information, can´t you just keep it on the server in a [`SESSION`](http://%60SESSION%60)?

Comment: actually i am keeping the login id and pwd in session variables. my scenario is 'there is link open box. onclick of it box for particular has to open . so i was using id of the box as ('box_id'.id) . so it was jus appearing in view source and moreover its not safe to jus send usr-id like this. so went for md5(usr-id) . i hope this is ok  '

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has some [encryption](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/encryption) plugins. You can encrypt your values before sending them, and decrypt them in php.